# Android push new instance of main Activity?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create/push-onto-stack a new Activity of the same main Activity in an Android application with an argument passed to the Activities constructor? Specifically from a Dialog object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fire off a new Intent with your argument in the extra.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class);
i.putExtra("some_key", someData);
startActivity(i);
```

To get the Extra in OnCreate, just do

```
getIntent().getExtras().getLong/getInt/getString/getWhatever
```